# Use equalizer or tool to hear better?

Tags: video, audio, sound-editing

I have a video made from a webcam. Its has three people talking. The problems with audio are

- Most of the speech are lower so i need to boost the volume up
- Some of the speech by one person is very high pitched
- Lots of low rumbling in the background.

When i put the volume up (say 200% with VLC for testing) the high pitch gets very loud causes ... i dont know what its called. Clips? Blows the audio?. The low rumbling and other sounds causes that too. How do i ignore the low and high and boost the volume so i can hear the speech in the center to low range?

Answer (score 0):

You could filter the wave form with a band-pass filter twice. Once for the high pitched voice and once for the low pitched sounds. Then you can adjust the volume and/or filter noice separately for these two wave forms. When you're done, reassemble/mix the wave forms again and it should be of better quality, at least when listening to it.

Comment: What application might i use? I dont need a new video file. Anything simple enough to listen to the video once is good enough. Maybe i can try VirtualDub but I am sure i cant boost volume there even if i can set the filters.

Comment: You could use VirtualDub to extract the audio track from the video. That's all you need, if I understood you right. Load this audio track in a tool like Cool Edit Pro or similar (Google is your friend) and apply the filters to the audio. You can (if needed) add the audio track back to the movie later with VirtualDub.